# Python : Why is: not None = True

Tags: python, boolean, nonetype

The title honestly says it all:
Why does `not None` return `True`. I have seen that `bool(None)` apparently returns `False`. Is there a good explanation as to why these two events occur this way ?

Edit: I guess what I'm really asking is what led to python implementing None as being a falsy type ?

Comment: What else should it return?

Comment: I guess in that case you could ask: why is None falsey ? Is there a reason behind this implementation ?

Comment: @Barmar I don't know, I was just not expecting not None to return a boolean...

Comment: You could also try `not 0`, `not []`, and `not ''` -- all are falsy values, so they will result in `True`. And you could try `not 1`, `not [0]`, and `not '0'`, which will all result in `False`.

Comment: `not <anything>` always returns a boolean. Why should it be different for `None`?

Comment: @FredLarson Alright, that does make sense, I guess now I'm just womdering how the choice determining what was Falsy or not was made

Comment: Basically, anything zero or empty will be falsy. The linked dupe has more detailed info.

Answer (score 1):

Because negating any [falsy value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) value will result in `True`.